# Honda Civic O2 Sensor

Tags: honda, sensor

Bought 02 upstream air fuel for 04 Honda Civic it came with a male connector while the old has a female connector the connector on the car is male so  I  cut the connector off the new sensor how do  I  join the wires?

New 02 colors: black, black, blue, white

Old 02 colors: black, black, green, white

Comment: blue = green, its the only one that does not match.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the O2 sensor wire question because it is an AFR sensor and therefore cannot be substituted and rewired.

Comment: Welcome to the site Oral.  Using all caps is bad practice for the internet in general, so I edited the question to have normal capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

This will not likely work. If the sensor is not the correct part number for the specific vehicle it is unlikely that it will match the exacting electrical specifications needed for the PCM to control and read the sensor. AFR sensors are matched to the PCM. Unlike so called "oxygen sensor" which can more often be interchanged across different engines and control systems.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @fredwilson on this one you probably just screwed your self by cutting the connector off. You should of taken the sensor back and gotten the one appropriate for your car.

In any case your going to have to cut the connector off the old sensor as well. Keep track of where the wires go into the connector and solder or crimp the connections.